# Windows 8 doesn't boot after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, boot, windows-8

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 I used Ubuntu Boot Repair (as usual) to reinstall the GRUB and visualize the other OS installed (ie. Windows 8). Unfortunately,this time something didn't work at all, and I am now not able to boot into Windows 8, which soon after selection in the GRUB starts and fails the Automatic Repair.

Even OS repristinating doesn't seem to work. I think I have installed the Ubuntu 12.04 boot loader in the same partition of the Win8 boot loader (sda2, EFI), so, as a results, Ubuntu boots perfectly, while Win8 doesn't. Is there a way to rescue Windows 8 without reinstalling it? Step by Step advice will be welcomed! XD

Comment: I recommend you following this instructions[(How To safely uninstall Ubuntu and restore Windows 8?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/240002/169736), then reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I'd follow one of the two possible answers provided, but could you help me with the code? I fear I'm not able to do all the procedure from the terminal without help...

Comment: please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Try to reboot and enter in your BIOS boot options. If you can see some kind of Windows 8 boot option then select it to boot and it should load your Windows 8.

PS: Mine works just as I said above :)

Comment: There's the Windows Boot Manager in between the boot options, but even selecting it instead of the grub won't solve the problem..